# Can't delete instance group in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, kubernetes

We have kubernetes running on a cluster in google cloud. Something happened to the cluster, and all of the nodes had the status `node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoSchedule`. We attempted to delete the cluster, but it is not working.

The instance groups all have the status

> This instance group is transforming.

The instances all have the status

> This instance is being deleted

The kubernetes clusters all have the status

> This cluster is being deleted

but when I click on a cluster it also says either

> timed out waiting for Google Compute Engine operation:
>   operation-1554925944268-58632688f6552-473a295c-305f8d99

or

> Googleapi: Error 400: There is a peering operation in progress on the
>   local or peer network. Try again later., badRequest.

It took a long time for the VM instances themselves to get deleted, but eventually they did.

However, the groups and clusters are not being deleted.

If I manually try to delete an instance group it says

> Google Compute Engine is not ready for use yet in the project. It may
>   take several minutes if Google Compute Engine has just been enabled,
>   or if this is the first time you use Google Compute Engine in the
>   project.

which makes no sense whatsoever.

Any help debugging this situation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [public issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/130259443) about instance groups stucked when trying to delete a cluster.

You could try to update your Google Kubernetes Engine cluster & nodes version.

Comment: lol I made that issue

Comment: I was trying to reproduce your issue and it worked for me. Can you try again as it may be fixed already?